# Menus in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hello am trying to implement an cashier like app however I came to a dificulty when implementing JPanels What would be in this case the best method to conver my frames to panels with different images? am trying to convert for example my main screen into 2 panels 1 would be the menu the other one a slide or set of images

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class PRINCIPAL extends JFrame {

    public PRINCIPAL(){
        setResizable(false);                    //Hace que la ventana sea no modificable
        setTitle("Projecto de Cajero UTC");     //Titulo para la parte de arriba
        setSize(957,760);                       //Tamaño de la app
        JLabel fondo;                           //Declaramos un label para el fondo
        ImageIcon inicio = new ImageIcon("src/main/java/Imagenes/INICIO.png");//Añadimos un icono parra el fondo
        fondo= new JLabel("",inicio,JLabel.LEFT);//Se añade el Fondo al centro en el centro
        fondo.setBounds(50,0,550,0);          //Pixeles calculados para la posicion del fondo respecto al frame
        add(fondo);                             //Añadir
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            //Ventana al centro
        
        
        
        
        JButton clickINICIO=new JButton("INICIO"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickINICIO.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickINICIO.setBounds(30,141,192,36);    //Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickINICIO);                  //añadir
        //clickINICIO.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickINICIO.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickINICIO.setOpaque(false);            ////
        //clickINICIO.setFocusable(false);////
        //clickINICIO.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        clickINICIO.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
        JLabel fondo;                           //Declaramos un label para el fondo
        ImageIcon inicio = new ImageIcon("src/main/java/Imagenes/DEPOSITO.png");//Añadimos un icono parra el fondo
        fondo= new JLabel("",inicio,JLabel.LEFT);//Se añade el Fondo al centro en el centro
        fondo.setBounds(50,0,550,0);          //Pixeles calculados para la posicion del fondo respecto al frame
        add(fondo);                             //Añadir
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            //Ventana al centro
        
  }
});
        
        
        JButton clickSALDO=new JButton("SALDO"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickSALDO.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickSALDO.setBounds(30,199,191,37);    //Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickSALDO);                  //añadir
        //clickSALDO.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickSALDO.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickSALDO.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickSALDO.setFocusable(false);////
        clickSALDO.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        JButton clickDEPOSITOS=new JButton("DEPOSITOS"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickDEPOSITOS.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickDEPOSITOS.setBounds(30,258,191,37);    //Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickDEPOSITOS);                  //añadir
        //clickDEPOSITOS.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickDEPOSITOS.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickDEPOSITOS.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickDEPOSITOS.setFocusable(false);////
        clickDEPOSITOS.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        JButton clickRETIROS=new JButton("RETIROS"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickRETIROS.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickRETIROS.setBounds(30,316,191,37);    //Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickRETIROS);                  //añadir
        //clickRETIROS.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickRETIROS.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickRETIROS.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickRETIROS.setFocusable(false);////
        clickRETIROS.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        
        
        JButton clickMOVIMIENTOS=new JButton("MOVIMIENTOS"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickMOVIMIENTOS.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickMOVIMIENTOS.setBounds(30,374,191,39);    //Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickMOVIMIENTOS);                  //añadir
        //clickMOVIMIENTOS.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickMOVIMIENTOS.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickMOVIMIENTOS.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickMOVIMIENTOS.setFocusable(false);////
        clickMOVIMIENTOS.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        
        JButton clickSERVICIOS=new JButton("SERVICIOS"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickSERVICIOS.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickSERVICIOS.setBounds(30,432,191,77);//Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickSERVICIOS);                  //añadir
        //clickSERVICIOS.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickSERVICIOS.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickSERVICIOS.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickSERVICIOS.setFocusable(false);////
        clickSERVICIOS.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        
        JButton clickAJUSTES=new JButton("AJUSTES"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickAJUSTES.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickAJUSTES.setBounds(30,528,191,39);//Tamaño del boton
        fondo.add(clickAJUSTES);                  //añadir
        //clickAJUSTES.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickAJUSTES.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickAJUSTES.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickAJUSTES.setFocusable(false);////
        clickAJUSTES.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        JButton clickSALIR=new JButton("SALIR"); //Declaramos el boton
        clickSALIR.setFont(new Font("Work Sans", Font.BOLD,20));//Letras
        clickSALIR.setBounds(30,586,191,39);//Tamaño del boton.
        fondo.add(clickSALIR);                  //añadir
        //clickSALIR.setContentAreaFilled(false);//
        //clickSALIR.setBorderPainted(false);// TRANSPARENTE
        //clickSALIR.setOpaque(false);            ////
        clickSALIR.setFocusable(false);////
        clickSALIR.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//Cambiar mouse al pasar el boton
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for the expected and the current behavior?

Comment: I would really like to know how you learned _Swing_ programming (just out of curiosity). In the meantime, I recommend that you visit this Web page [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: As I've told others before: Start with your data & functional *model*. Build that out, (JUnit or other) test it all, then at the END design a GUI around it